# Pause add to cart function after ajax

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento-2.0

I'm generating a filename via AJAX Jquery. Now I need this filename to be saved. My current process is to call a controller that will do the image saving and it will return a filename/filepath back. Using this new filepath I'm inserting this to a textfield as a value so that when the `Add to Cart` function is triggered it will get the generated filepath value and save it as custom option.

But the problem is that the `Add to cart` function is being triggered even when the Ajax Jquery hasn't finish it's processing. How can I put the `Add to cart` function trigger onhold until the generated filename is returned by the Ajax. I'm thinking of something like a callback function.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
jQuery("#product-addtocart-button").on('click', function() {
        var canvas = jQuery('canvas.canvas');
        var canvasImage = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7);

        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          url: UPLOADER_URL,
          data: {
             imgBase64: canvasImage
          }
        }).done(function(response) {                
            last_option.val(response.filename);         
            console.log("Generated filename", response.filename);   
             // TRIGGER ADD TO CART FUNCTION HERE
             // BUT THE ADD TO CART IS BEING TRIGGERED EVEN IF THE AJAX IS NOT YET FINISH
        });

    });
```

Comment: What browsers do you support?

Comment: @BenCrook well I think all browser should be support specially Chrome, Firefox, Safari

Comment: If you don't need to support IE take a look at async and await - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
jQuery("#product-addtocart-button").on('click', function(e) {
    var self = this;

    if (!jQuery(self).hasClass('processing')) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var canvas = jQuery('canvas.canvas');
        var canvasImage = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                jQuery(self).addClass('processing');
            },
            url: UPLOADER_URL,
            data: {
                imgBase64: canvasImage
            }
        }).done(function(response) {                
            last_option.val(response.filename);         
            console.log("Generated filename", response.filename);
            e.currentTarget.click();

            jQuery(self).removeClass('processing');
        });
    }
});
```